# Question with Definition of a function in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand this to be the definition of a function in set theory: Function (map) is a relation (X,Y,R) such that for every x∈X there is unique element (x,y)∈R. My question is why then we go into further depth to classify functions, like one to one if by definition a function has one unique value y for every x?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, things like one-to-one are just other properties that functions can also have on top of what makes them functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 basic properties a binary relation $R\subseteq A\times B$ might or might not have, independently of each other:

(1) $R$ is full on its domain: $\forall a\in A\,\exists b\in B:(a,b)\in R$

(2) $R$ is full on its codomain: $\forall b\in B\,\exists a\in A:(a,b)\in R$

(3) $R$ is a partial function: $(a,b)\in R\land (a,b')\in R\implies b=b'$

(4) $R$ is one-to-one: $(a,b)\in R\land (a',b)\in R\implies a=a'$

$R$ is a function if it satisfies (1) and (3).
$R$ is a one-to-one function (injective function) if it satisfies (1), (3) and (4).
$R$ is a surjective function if it satisfies (1), (2) and (3).
Finally, $R$ is a bijection if it satisfies all (1)-(4).